# File doesn't open using fopen() function in C

Tags: files, c

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on VMWare Fusion.
I have no idea why the file doesn't open using fopen() function in C.
The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
          char *fname = "file.txt";
          FILE *fp;

          if((fp = fopen(fname, "w")) != NULL) {
                 fprintf(stderr, "open error for %s, errno = %d\n", fname, errno);
                 exit(1);
         }
         printf("opened!\n");
         free(fp);
         return 0;
}
```

And the result is below.

```
$ ./a.out 
open error for file.txt, errno = 0
```

My Ubuntu memory is like that.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           393M  2.1M  391M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   14G  3.9G  79% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           393M   16K  393M   1% /run/user/122
tmpfs           393M   36K  393M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 5):

this statement

```
if((fp = fopen(fname, "w")) != NULL) {
```

should be:

```
if((fp = fopen(fname, "w")) == NULL) {
```

I.E. the posted code is checking for the success condition and calling it an error

on a related note:

this statement:

```
free(fp);
```

is NOT how to close a file

rather use:

```
fclose( fp );
```

also,

```
df
```

tells disk space usage

To display the information about files use:

```
ls -al
```

Strongly suggest making extensive use of the `man` pages for any functions you want to use.